# Upload Base64 image string from objective-c to MVC .Net C#

Tags: c#, objective-c, ios, base64

I'm trying to upload a Base64 image string from iOS (using NSData+Base64) to MVC .Net. The upload is ok, but when I try to convert string back to Image, an exception is thrown at line:

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageString);
```

Exception: *"Invalid length for a Base-64 char array"*

The imageString length converted in iOS is 944062.

To verify the length, I converted the same image in .Net using

```
string fota = ImageToBase64(Image.FromFile(@"C:\PR\Source\Servicea\bin\Imag043.jpg"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

and the size was 203956. And the original image file size is 156,967.

Both methods shouldn't convert the image returning the same string? Anybody had this problem before? Tks

**Update:** After many tests, I decided to use [ASIHTTPRequest lib.](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) Tks all.

Comment: 203956 is a much more plausible Base64 encoded length for the original length 156967, so your encoding must be wrong. Perhaps start with smaller data and verify the result on http://www.base64encode.org.

Comment: @MartinR I might be mistaken but I think 156967 was the file size, not the length of the Base64 string.

Comment: @MartinR How I can verify if my original file is an image?

Comment: @MartinR However, it is interesting to note that the iOS `imageString` length (944062) does not divide by 4 evenly.

Comment: @dtryon: Yes, that is what I meant. If the original length is 156967, then a Base64 encoded length 203956 is plausible. A encoded length 944062 looks quite wrong.

Comment: Can you post the Objective-C code that converts the image to Base64 string?

Comment: @djserva: You could test your encoding algorithm with small data instead of an entire image. - And without seeing the encoding code we cannot really help.

Comment: @dtryon: The encoding method could add newline or carriage-return/newlines to the Base64 output, in this case the result length need not be a multiple of 4.

Comment: @MartinR Do you mean after encoding to Base64?  Would you then expect that the `imageString` value would not be padded correctly when received by the server? 944062 vs 203956 seems like a lot of additional bytes (as you pointed out earlier).

Comment: @dtryon I use [this class](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html) and the call is `NSString *imageString = [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage,1) base64EncodedString];`

Comment: Perhaps we should wait until the OP provides more information how the image data is encoded and sent to the server. - (The only thing I wanted to say is: If the original file size is 156967, then the encoded length cannot be 944062, so there must be an error with the encoding.)

Comment: @djserva: Can you verify that the `NSString *imageString` in iOS and the `imageString` on the server have the same length and the same contents?

Comment: @MartinR in iOS: 944062. In .Net: 203956 and the begin of content is the same, but in iOS there are line feeds and carriages return

Comment: And when you sent the string from iOS to the server: Does the *server* receive the same string of length 944062?

Comment: Are you attempting to send an image to the server? If so there is a much easier way of doing this with multipart form values

Comment: @Tony I'm looking for a more lightweight request string than using _multipart/form-data; boundary=_ to send an image and a string in the same request, but it's becoming harder than the project code. So, how is this way @Tony?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static char base64EncodingTable[64] = {
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
    'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
    'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
    'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '/'
};

+ (NSString *) base64StringFromData: (NSData *)data length: (int)length {
    unsigned long ixtext, lentext;
    long ctremaining;
    unsigned char input[3], output[4];
    short i, charsonline = 0, ctcopy;
    const unsigned char *raw;
    NSMutableString *result;

    lentext = [data length];
    if (lentext < 1)
        return @"";
    result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity: lentext];
    raw = [data bytes];
    ixtext = 0;

    while (true) {
        ctremaining = lentext - ixtext;
        if (ctremaining <= 0)
            break;
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            unsigned long ix = ixtext + i;
            if (ix < lentext)
                input[i] = raw[ix];
            else
                input[i] = 0;
        }
        output[0] = (input[0] & 0xFC) >> 2;
        output[1] = ((input[0] & 0x03) << 4) | ((input[1] & 0xF0) >> 4);
        output[2] = ((input[1] & 0x0F) << 2) | ((input[2] & 0xC0) >> 6);
        output[3] = input[2] & 0x3F;
        ctcopy = 4;
        switch (ctremaining) {
            case 1:
                ctcopy = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                ctcopy = 3;
                break;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < ctcopy; i++)
            [result appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%c", base64EncodingTable[output[i]]]];

        for (i = ctcopy; i < 4; i++)
            [result appendString: @"="];

        ixtext += 3;
        charsonline += 4;

        if ((length > 0) && (charsonline >= length))
            charsonline = 0;
    }
    return result;
}
```